# Angular: Child component modifies parent object, possible NG0100: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-changedetection

I am trying out a new architectural approach where child components "compose" na object held by the parent.

Consider the following definitions:

```js
interface TypeA {
  typeAProp: number,
}

interface TypeB {
  typeBProp: string,
}

interface MyObject {
  type: 'typeA' | 'typeB', // yes, strings
  content: TypeA | TypeB
}
```

Now, I have a component `Parent` that gets an object of type `MyObject` as `@Input()` (an API response) and depending on the value set on `type` either displays `TypeAComponent` or `TypeBComponent`:

```js
@Component({
....
})
export class ParentComponent {
  @Input() public myObject: MyObject;
}
```

```html
<select [(ngModel)]="myObject.type">
 <option value="typeA">Type A</option>
 <option value="typeB">Type A</option>
</select>

<ng-container [ngSwitch]="myObject.type">
  <TypeAComponent
    [(obj)]="myObject"
    *ngSwitchCase="typeA">
  </TypeAComponent>

  <TypeBComponent
    [(obj)]="myObject"
    *ngSwitchCase="typeB">
  </TypeAComponent>
```

Now, as one can see quite easily, I want to modify the object (or to be more precise, the `content` object of `MyObject`) inside my child components.

As the child components know how the respective interface looks like, it seems to be a good place. In most cases, I want to display some sort of form to make it possible to modify the values inside of `content`.

But if the original type was `typeB`, and the user switched to `typeA` in the parents `select`, the properties are still from `typeB`, so I would need to re-initialize the `content` object.

```js
@Component({
....
})
export class TypeAComponent {
  private _obj: MyObject | null = null;
  @Input() public set obj(o: MyObject | null) { 
    this._obj = o; 
    this._obj.content = {
      typeAProp: 99,
    };

    this.objChange.emit(this._obj);
  };
  @Output() public objChange: EventEmitter<MyObject> = new EventEmitter();
}
```

(And roughly the same for `TypeBComponent`).

This approach would have certain benefits:

- Only the child components need to know on how `content` has to look like to satisfy type requirements
- The parent component stays "clean" as it does not have to be cluttered with a lot of if/elses for the construction of `content`.

However, my approach from above triggers a `NG0100: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` error. I know why this happens and how I could (hacky) get around it, but that's not what I am after.

Is my approach architecturally wrong? Is it "bad practice" to modify a parent object from it's child? Is there a good way to do this?

In my real application I would have at least 5-10 different `types` and each type has at least 5-10 properties, so a "declarative" approach would be good.

Comment: How is the parent listening the changes made in either of the child components? you have `objChange` as `EventEmitter` emitting a value but in the parent, you have `[(obj)]="myObject"`...  shouldn't be (myObject) for the event? I have the feeling that using double data binding is a bad approach

Comment: Simply by double data binding, yes. But I don't quite understand your question..... Would a service give any benefits?